# What are the irreducible representations (Clebsch-Gordan decomposition) of $\mathbf{10}\otimes \mathbf{3}$ in $SU(3)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

Since a rank-3 tensor has 10 components and a rank-1 tensor has 3 components in $SU(3)$, I know that we are searching for the different irreducible representations of the tensor $v_{ijk}w_{l}$.

The fully symmetric part is equivalent to a rank-4 totally symmetric tensor with $v_{(ijk}w_{l)} = x_{ijkl}$. This will have 15 components.

But, I am not sure how to account for the rest 15. A possible setting includes a rank-2 tensor accounting for 6, rank-(1,1) accounting for 8 and one scalar using traceless property. But this is just me fixing the numbers without derivation.

$$\mathbf{10 \otimes 3 = 15 \ \oplus \ ?}$$

Comment: You can use [Young tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch–Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)#Young_tableaux) for such decompositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tensor notation:
$$v_{(ijk)}w_l 
=
x_{(ijkl)} + \varepsilon_{ml(k} y_{ij)}^m
+ \underbrace{\varepsilon_{l(jk}z_{i)}}_{0}
$$
$$
y^i_{(ij)} = 0
$$
Or:
$$\mathbf{10 \otimes 3 = 15 \ \oplus \ 15^{\prime}}$$

Or by using Young tables:

[image]